# Check if explicit cast succeed

Tags: c++, casting

I convert a `double` variable to `void pointer`:

```
double doub = 3;
void *pointer = &doub;
```

If I convert the void pointer to **int** , not to **double**:

```
int i = *((int *) pointer);
```

I get : `i=0`.

How can I check if the cast succeed and the returned value is 0 since the original value is 0, or failed?

Comment: You are not casting, you are just reading the memory where the double resides as if it were an integer. Do this way: `int i = (int)(*pointer);`

Comment: Casts never fail, with exception of `dynamic_cast`

Comment: @AndréPuel, what is the difference? how can I check now if the conversion succeed?

Comment: @JarkkoL, So how should I do it?

Comment: What is it that you actually are trying to do? Because your original questions makes no sense considering my previous comment. If you just try to cast double to int: `int i=int(doub);`

Comment: @JarkkoL, I would like to get the original type of what the void pointer refers to. Possible?

Comment: You don't. You cast back to the original type or it's undefined. You need to either know what the original type was, or introduce some kind of metadata so you know whether the cast is valid.

Comment: Not possible. You have lost the type information when you did cast to void*. You have to explicitly know the type, i.e. cast back to double*

Comment: @molbdnilo, I cast a pointer of double to int, and get 0. Any ideas?

Comment: @user3165438 It's undefined, but that's not an idea, it's a fact. You threw away the type information, and you can't get it back. You need to rethink your code.

Comment: You get 0 because the memory representation of double(3.0) just happens to have the lowest 32-bits set to 0. Try something like 1.23456789 and you will get different result.

Comment: @JarkkoL, so how can I check if the conversion succeed?

Comment: It never 'succeeds' in the way you want (C++ isn't dynamically typed language). Do `int i=(int)*((double*)pointer);` That tells that the memory address has double type and then you convert it from double to int.

Comment: @JarkkoL, I do not want it to success in case it doesn't have to! I just like to know if it HAS to. Would appreciate ANY idea!

Comment: Formulate your original question so that it describes what you actually want to do. If you want a mechanism to abstract away the type (i.e. similar to casting to void*), and get the type back if it matches the original type then you can do it with dynamic_cast & some template magic. But state this in the original question if it's what you want.

Comment: @JarkkoL, I would like to convert the void pointer to int, and if it fails to convert it to double, and if it fails convert it to string, and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Because C++ isn't dynamically typed language you can't do it straight with `void*` but you have to use `dynamic_cast` and some template wrapper:

```
struct type_base
{
    virtual ~type_base() {}
    template<typename T> T *get_value()
    {
        if(type<T>* t=dynamic_cast<type<T>*>(this))
            return &t->value;
        return 0;
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct type: type_base
{
    T value;
};
```

This enables you to 'lose' type information and query it back for different types as follows:

```
type<int> v;
v.value=1;
type_base *p=&v;
float *x=p->template get_value<float>(); // fails
int *y=p->template get_value<int>(); // works
```