# Convert void* to a dynamic type

Tags: c++, casting, void-pointers

I have a double variable `i`, that is converted to a void pointer named `pointer`:

```
 double i = 3; 
 void *pointer = &i;
```

When I like to convert the void pointer back to double I used:

```
 double p = *((double*) pointer);
```

I would like to convert the void pointer to the type I will send as a char*:

```
 char* myType= typeid(i).name();//get the name of type of "i"
 int p = *((myType*) pointer); // how to implement?
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You should not use C style casts in C++. Prefer `dynamic_cast` and `static_cast`.

Comment: @RedX, can you please provide sample? Thanks

Comment: [What about googling for a tutorial?](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/44-type-conversion-and-casting/)

Comment: In the second code, you are typecasting `void` pointer to `double` but assigning to `int` variable. This will give an error. Not able to figure out what exactly you are trying to do in third one???

Comment: @Arpit, I like to get a type name as an argument, and make conversion of the void pointer to the given type, where type is a system type. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible; if the type is not known until runtime, what would the compiler use as the object's type?

Comment: You can cast all over the place. The compiler will compile. Loads of undefined behaviour but the compiler will shut up and compile toer than (myType*) which meakes no sense.

Comment: Close duplicate of your original question posted ~30min before this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25745712/check-if-explicit-cast-succeed/25746876#25746876

Comment: A variable holds no information of the type it contains (at runtime). You cannot just try to use `typeid` and expect it to work (plus it is a GNU plugin and gives extra overhead)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
char* myType= typeid(i).name();//get the name of type of "i"
int p = *((myType*) pointer); // how to implement?
```

use

```
typedef decltype(i) myType;
myType p = *((myType*) pointer);
```

or better:

```
typedef decltype(i) myType;
auto p = *reinterpret_cast<myType*>(pointer);
```

Works with c++11 or later. If you want to `decltype` on older c++ compilers, it is emulated in boost.

**Edit.** This is probably different from what you wanted to do, which I suppose is something like this:

```
void myFunction(void* unknownParam) {
    typedef (realTypeOf unknownParam) RealType; // <-- this is not real c++
    RealType &a = *reinterpret_cast<RealType*>(unknownParam)
    //do stuff using 'a'
}
```

This is not possible in C++, but there is a reason: it doesn't make much sense.
And the reason is that for `myFunction` to be valid the `//do stuff using 'a'` part should be valid for whatever type `RealType` ends up being. As such, it cannot rely on any feature the `RealType` type have: it cannot use any of its methods, it cannot use any operator, it cannot even know whether it is a class or not. Basically, you cannot do anything more with it than what you would already be able to do on a `void*`, so giving the type a name doesn't really help you much.

A language feature that is similar to what you want (but not quite it) is type reflection, which is not present in C++, but you can find it in language such as Java, Objective-C or C#. Basically, you ask the object itself if it has a certain method, and eventually call it. An example in Objective-C

```
-(void)myFunction:(id)unknownParam {
    if([unknownParam respondsToSelector:@selector(myMethod)])
        [unknownParam performSelector:@selector(myMethod)]
}
```

Comment: it is bad practice to use C style casts in C++, because it is not clear whether you are performing a semantic conversion (`static_cast`), reinterpreting the address as something else (`reinterpret_cast`), or removing a `const` qualifier (`const_cast`), so you may think you are doing one while in reality the compiler is using another one, leading to unexpected behavior.

Comment: Thanks again. Is it possible to send the decltype as parameter?

Comment: yes. You can use `decltype(expression)` wherever you would use a type name (i.e., declaring variables, class members, parameters and return value of functions, cast expressions, template parameters, constructor calls...)

Comment: Thanks. I understand it is possible. Can you please post an examle how to implement? I would like to send to the method the void pointer and the type. The method do the cast. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

C/C++ does not work well to interchange datatype like for example JavaScript variables
Format of int value will be different than double value format (floating point) in binary

You cannot get original data type using typeid after it has been casted to void*. Also note that typeid will have different output on different OS and compilers

```
double dValue = 77.7;
void* pValue = &dValue;

//output "pV" / pointer void (depending on compiler and OS)
std::cout << typeid(dValue).name() << std::endl;
```

To cast from void* using string you can make rules like following. Or you can try to use C++ template functions in specific cases.

```
int iOutValue = 0;
double dOutValue = 0;

char* name = "double";
if(!strcmp(name, "int"))
{
    iOutValue = *((int*)pValue);
}
else if(!strcmp(name, "double"))
{
    dOutValue = *((double*)pValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If instead of passing around `void*` you used some kind of variant type, you would be able to convert it back.

If you use a string to indicate the type you will need some kind of map from string to actual type. Although you can go from type to string, there is no conversion back.

Assuming you know your underlying data is always numeric in some way, there are ways to have special discrete variants that only contain numbers. The simplest would be to store a union of a 64-bit int and a double, and some flag indicating which one you have, and then a method to convert to any numeric type, `asDouble()`, `asLong()` etc.